# How to plot in double Log scale from CSV file?

Tags: plotting

How to plot in double Log scale from CSV file?
I tried to use ListLogLogPlot but it scales only x axis. CSV file consists of two columns with comma:
0.1,6.2262
0.2,6.2324
0.3,6.2372
0.4,6.243
0.5,6.252
....

```
ListLogLogPlot[
     Import["/home/A.
    csv", {"Data", All, {1, 2}}], 
     Joined -> True, PlotRange -> {All, All}, Frame -> True, 
     BaseStyle -> {FontSize -> 18}, ImageSize -> 1000, 
     FrameLabel -> {MaTeX["B,\\,\\textrm{T}", Magnification -> 24/12], 
       MaTeX["R(\\theta_{1}),\\,\\Omega", Magnification -> 24/12]}]
```

Comment: If you could edit your post to show 10-20 lines from `Import["/home/A.csv",{"Data",All,{1,2}}]` then others can try to figure out why `ListLogLogPlot` isn't working for you. `ListLogLogPlot[{{1,3},{5,8},{12,12},{18,15},{20,20}}]` seems to scale both axes for me.

Comment: @Bill, How would you plot this points from csv file in log scale for x and y?

Comment: @Bill, {{0.1, 6.2262}, {0.2, 6.2324}, {0.3, 6.2372}, {0.4, 6.243}, {0.5, 
  6.252}, {0.6, 6.2656}, {0.7, 6.2824}, {0.8, 6.3004}, {0.9, 
  6.3175}, {1, 6.3333}, {1.1, 6.3493}, {1.2, 6.3669}, {1.3, 
  6.3874}, {1.4, 6.4118}, {1.5, 6.4398}, {1.6, 6.471}, {1.7, 
  6.5048}, {1.8, 6.5407}, {1.9, 6.5784}, {2, 6.6177}, {2.1, 
  6.6585}, {2.2, 6.7007}, {2.3, 6.7439}, {2.4, 6.788}, {2.5, 
  6.8328}, {2.6, 6.8782}, {2.7, 6.9239}, {2.8, 6.9697}, {2.9, 
  7.0156}, {3, 7.0621}, {3.1, 7.1095}, {3.2, 7.1586}, {3.3, 
  7.2096}, {3.4, 7.263}}

Comment: Wonderful. Just what we needed to answer this. Now I see exactly the problem. Your y range is small enough that the log of y  looks almost like just y. You and I thought it wasn't doing log of y because of that. If I subtract 6 from all your y and then do a log log plot `points=Map[#-{0,6}&,<<yourdata>>];ListLogLogPlot[points]` shows a much bigger distance between .4 and .6 than between 1.0 and 1.2. If you fake some data with a y range of 10 or 100 fold in y inside Excel and do exactly what you did then you should clearly see that `ListLogLogPlot` is taking the log of both x and y.